# Using Vs code to run c++ with windows api

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, winapi, mingw32

I'm trying to implement a c++ code with windows API in VS Code. But the extension available at vs code is not supporting API functions. The error is

```
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KAVI-P~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZZwMdN.o:user.cpp:(.text+0x153): undefined reference to `NetUserEnum'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KAVI-P~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZZwMdN.o:user.cpp:(.text+0x2bb): undefined reference to `NetApiBufferFree'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KAVI-P~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZZwMdN.o:user.cpp:(.text+0x390): undefined reference to `NetUserGetInfo'
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/11.2.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\KAVI-P~1\AppData\Local\Temp\ccZZwMdN.o:user.cpp:(.text+0x3b1): undefined reference to `NetApiBufferFree'
```

Comment: Did you link with `Netapi32.lib` like the documentation tells you: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmapibuf/nf-lmapibuf-netapibufferfree](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmapibuf/nf-lmapibuf-netapibufferfree)  your bug is probably in your `tasks.json`

Comment: You should compile with `-lnetapi32`.